# Sharing Youtube Video to Facebook using Share Button no thumbnail

Tags: facebook, youtube, share, facebook-sharer

i am facing a problem while sharing a youtube video from my website using facebook share button,
the website contains Article, pictures and Videos imported from Youtube, all meta tags are well formatted and provided. but only with youtube when i try to share a video thumbnail is not shown !!! in the other side the description and the title all is shown and right.
i tried to check what facebook is recognizing from my website through (developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and the thumbnail is there !!!!
i also tried to take the video url directly from youtube and paste it to facebook and the thumbnail is shown, only when i click the share button from my website to share a youtube video the thumbnail disappear.

please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: am building the website using C#.NET
here a link to a video list, just click on one and a popup will appear, try to share it using the facebook share button below it and notice the absence of the thumbnail,
http://roya.tv/Home.aspx?BlocksPage=HJ_Season2#